# type_traits errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

When in VS2010 I add

```
#include <iostream>
```

to console aplication template I get many errors in type_traits

```
error C2275: '_Ty' : illegal use of this type as an expression  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\type_traits  762 1   pcl1 (Visual Studio 2010)
error C3861: '__is_standard_layout': identifier not found   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\type_traits  762 1   pcl1 (Visual Studio 2010)
error C2955: 'std::_Cat_base' : use of class template requires template argument list   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\type_traits  763 1   pcl1 (Visual Studio 2010)
error C2275: '_Ty' : illegal use of this type as an expression  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\type_traits  768 1   pcl1 (Visual Studio 2010)
an many others...
```

I don't know why why but I think it's somehow connected with the fact that I'm using both VS2012 and VS2010. How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

From the error message it is clear that your VS2010 project is somehow being directed to look in the VS2012 include directory, c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include.  This is never a good idea.

Check your project settings under C/C++ / General / Additional Include Directories.  Remove any references to compiler include directories.  The correct directories for your compiler will be automatically located by the system.

Comment: Indeed there are references to VS2012 include and libraries 
    C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include

and in library:

    C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib

But without them I have problems not only with my application but also with running template projects.